# How do I load a string into a FileStream without going to disk?

Tags: c#, filestream

```
string abc = "This is a string";
```

How do I load abc into a FileStream?

```
FileStream input = new FileStream(.....);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a `MemoryStream` then?

Comment: Why would you want to? Why not something like a MemoryStream?

Comment: Does it have to be a File Stream?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question, http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/273281-loading-string-into-filestream

Comment: @MarkKram: Why does it sound like homework? Because it doesn't start with "My client/boss wants me to..."?

Comment: it is not a homework i want to ask that question in here.Ok i think i will use memory stream

Comment: @musefan: No, if you look at the link that I posted and compare the OP's question you will see that it is phrased and formatted the same  exactly way, even down to the number or dot in between the to parenthesis.

Comment: In support of Mark: the original question is 6+ years old...  I'd say either homework or interview.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) instead...

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(abc));
```

---

remember a MemoryStream (just like a FileStream) needs to be closed when you have finished with it. You can always place your code in a using block to make this easier...

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(abc)))
{
   //use the stream here and don't worry about needing to close it
}
```

NOTE: If your string is Unicode rather than ASCII you may want to specify this when converting to a Byte array. Basically, a Unicode character takes up 2 bytes instead of 1. Padding will be added if needed (e.g. `0x00 0x61` = "a" in unicode, where as in ASCII `0x61` = "a")